# Bitcoin HD Wallet using C#

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, client, bitcoin-core-development, bip44

What packages do I need to use for creating Bitcoin HD Wallet in C# using BIP44?

How can I connect to a remote Bitcoin Node to read all the deposit transactions received by various child addresses in the HD Wallet?

Which Node Client can I use for this?

Comment: You can use [NBitcoin](https://github.com/MetacoSA/NBitcoin) library or Bitcoin Core JSON-RPC

Comment: Thank you @Prayank I am using NBitcoin library to create the addresses with BIP44 in a HD Wallet, using path m/44'/0'/0'/0/. I couldn't be see any of the child addresses when I add the seed of the wallet to Bitcoin Core. Can you please point me to any references that will show the steps to creating a HD Wallet with child addresses using NBitcoin and the process for adding this wallet to Bitcoin core?

Answer (score 4):

I advise you just to rely on https://github.com/dgarage/NBXplorer/

This is an API more flexible and more stable than Bitcoin Core to manage HD wallets. There is a C# client, and it integrate nicely with NBitcoin.

You can create PSBTs from it, ready to sign with NBitcoin. (Disclaimer: I am the main maintainer for both NBitcoin and NBXplorer)

---

In regard to the follow-up questions:

- [NBXplorer Documentation](https://github.com/dgarage/NBXplorer/blob/master/docs/API.md)
- [NBitcoin Documentation](https://programmingblockchain.gitbook.io/programmingblockchain/)
- A small [multisig wallet example](https://github.com/dgarage/NBXplorer/blob/master/Examples/MultiSig/Program.cs)

`NBXplorer.Client` is the name of the nuget package to call the documented API.